# How to create an acronym of autocomple in flutter?

Tags: flutter, autocomplete, lint

When you type the acronyms **STF** or **STL** in flutter in **vscode**, it creates a class already with the pattern and the pointers to be able to edit the name, is it possible to do something like that for a custom acronym? For example if I use a standard model of body for the screens of an app, when I type **BDY** it auto completes with that class.

Comment: You can create snippets in vs code such that when you start typing the short codes you provided everything starts falling in place sequentially

Answer (score 1):

These are called live templates

In Android Studio go to Settings (Preferences on Mac) > Editor > Live Templates.

Expand the Flutter option. You should see some live templates already defined. To create a new one click the + add button on the right and choose Live templates.

Then in template text add the widget yiu wish to create

Comment: There's only mention of vscode and not Android studio.

Comment: Checking the similar question, I found that in vscode the name of this is snippet.

Comment: Yeah in vs code it is snippets